# Uniform convergence and interchange of limits

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$. Each function $f_n(x)$ is continuous, but the limit function $f(x)$ is not continuous:
$$
    f(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  0, 0\leq x<1\\
                  1, x=1\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
$$

**Question 1:** How can we prove that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f_n(x))=1
$$
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x))=0
$$

**Question 2:** Is uniform convergence of $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a sufficient condition to get the same result if we interchange the limits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1:**

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f_n(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} x^n = 1^n = 1$$

because, for every $n$, the function $x\mapsto x^n$ is continuous.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{x\to 1} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$$

On the other hand, if $x<1$ (*we can assume this when calculating $\lim_{x\to 1}$*), then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = 0$$

So $$\lim_{x\to 1}\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) =\lim_{x\to 1} 0 = 0$$

---

**Question 2:**
Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What I didn't get by myself is the assumption $x<1$, now it's clear. Regarding question #2: Is there any theorem that addresses such property?

Comment: @Konstantin Are the functions $f_n$ continuous?

Comment: Can you give some hints for both continuous and discontinuous cases?

Comment: @Konstantin Well, if $f_n$ are continuous, then $f$ (the limit function) is continuous by a theorem, and everything just falls out because $\lim_{x\to x_0} f_n(x)=f_n(x)$. Not sure about when $f_n$ are discontinuous. Will think about it.

Comment: So we apply uniform limit theorem and `f` is continuous. But why everything "just falls out"?

Comment: @Konstantin Yeah, since $f(x)$ by definition is $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$, you get that $$f(x_0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{x\to x_0} f_n(x)$$ because $f_n$ are all continuous.  But you also know that $f$ is continuous, so you have $$f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$$